# Problem with HTML, CSS table rendering when many columns

Tags: html, css

I have developed a way to insert excel files in WordPress
The document is converted in HTML. Table header is in its own div container, header float over content table when user scroll down.

Problem : Table columns does not reader as expected for  table version with 14 columns.

Here are two live pages :

https://www.aircom.ca/fra/produits/pompes-a-vide-elmo-rietschle/pompes-a-vide-a-palettes-lubrifiees/
renders ok  / 10 columns

https://www.aircom.ca/fra/produits/surpresseurs-a-deplacement-positif_gardner-denver_montreal/sutorbilt-legend/
probleme with header / 14 columns
in firefox renders 1px right  off
in IE 11 renders 1px right  off
in chrome renders 1px left + 1px up off

the inspector in chrome and firefox dont help 
tried to force widh of header table, force border to none : does not work ?

Has anyone ever encountered such a situation?

Comment: Please read [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and then create a [mcve] of your problem in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by taking the problem code to a simpler version.
"An exercise I should have done before posting a request for help!"

The inheritance of style sheet properties was the problem.
The Web site has been evolving since 2009. Page layout, and widgets moification, replacing, adding. The inital css logic ( cascading properties ) is more a difficulty than an adavantage now.
A bettter practice here would be to replace the rules by  ID selector for each table definition.

Thank you Stackoverflow.com / pete for interacting.